# how to add dependency in pydantic models in such a way that it alters the schema as well

Tags: dependencies, schema, jsonschema, pydantic

I have a geometry class, I have wrapper class , I have a mesh_motion_list class and I have json_spec_model class. all inherited from base model of pydantic. In json_spec_model I have union of geometry name geometry_list and union of wrappers named wrapper_list and mesh_motion_list. So now,  if a user selects geometry he needs to enter geometry name and geometry type. then user needs to select a wrapper and within a wrapper he needs to select geometry_name. if the selected geometry has a type solid then when user selects the geometry in wrapper he should be automatically given suggestion to select mesh_motion_list like as default snippet or something.  and if the selected geometry type is not solid then mesh_motion_list is not required.
create pydantic code for this.

I tried @root_validator and other validators but it does not alter the jsonSchema.